# Python - take a list and use it as parameter in a function

Tags: python

I have a function that takes in 3 parameters, and I have a list that contains 3 arguments.

I want to use this list as the function's parameter, how do I do it?

for example:

```
def get_result(x, y, z):
    'do_something'
vlist = [1,2,3]
get_result(vlist)
```

Comment: Use `get_result(*vlist)`

Comment: `get_result(*vlist)` would do the job! This will implicitly split your list into individual elements.

Comment: @kmario23 it's not implicit if you require an explicit operator to perform it :p

Comment: Thank guys!! It solved my problem!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unpack using the `*` 'splat' operator -> `get_result(*vlist)`

Comment: Who down voted this? It's exactly the right answer?